How to fix django-filer 404 error on DigitalOcean?
I have a django-cms app running on DigitalOcean. Creating folders and uploading files with filer works perfectly.
When downloading the uploaded files I get a 404 Error - for example on this url:
https://my_app.ondigitalocean.app/en/media/filer_public/39/d9/39d9ff20-1aa8-48e5-9b8f-113fc71e534b/atest.pdf/
The file is present in the filesystem:

settings.py
MEDIA_URL = "media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR / "media")

Everything is working fine on the local development server with DEBUG=True but also fails when DEBUG=False.

double check your settings.py for MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT

@m.piras They should be ok. I updated the question to include them.

could you try rewriting them as
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

if you are using nginx you could also post your configuration for the media path

does it work without leading / ?

When DEBUG=True, Django is directly managing static and media files. This behavior changes using DEBUG=False, for performance and security reasons. Usually in production static and media files are managed by a web server like Nginx. You should have a configuration similar to this:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_app.ondigitalocean.app;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/my_app.sock;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /path/to/your/project/media/;  # this must be what you have in MEDIA_ROOT
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /path/to/your/project/static/;
    }
}


Thanks, this is not a solution suitable for me, but maybe someone else.

Answer 1
After some search I found this question:
Why does DEBUG=False setting make my django Static Files Access fail?
After changing urls.py the files were served perfectly.
...
from django.urls import re_path
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns += (
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)

But!
My media folder was situated in the project folder (where manage.py lives) and was deleted every time the app was newly deployed, so:
Answer 2
I went for using django-storages.
https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
Create a Spaces Object Storage on DigitalOcean (or any other Cloudstorage) and change settings.py:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'storages', # add storages after installing it with pip
    ...
]

...

AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv("AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "False")
AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("AWS_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", "False")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "your_bucket_name"
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {"CacheControl": "max-age=86400"}
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "fra1" # might be different for you
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = "https://fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com" # might be different for you
AWS_LOCATION = "a_folder_name"
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3.S3Storage"

Note
Although I am using Django >= 5 the recommended style (see below) did not work for me, so i kept to the old style.
STORAGES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3.S3Storage",
        "OPTIONS": {
          ...your_options_here
        },
    },
}

